# Entity Framework Code First: How can I model a Customer / Address relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

Here is my simplified model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int MailingAddressID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MailingAddressID")]
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerID")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

When I try and create the database I get the following error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Customer_MailingAddress' on table 'Customers' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

I don't understand what the problem is. I understand that a Customer with an Address cannot be deleted and also that an Address which is a Customer's Mailing Address can also not be deleted.

This fits with my design because if a Customer has one or more addresses, then one must be a mailing address and that address can not be deleted.

So what am I missing here? Thanks!

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention that I tried adding the following line in the OnModelBuilding method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.MailingAddressID).IsOptional();
```

This allows the database to be built, however when adding a customer I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "Customer_MailingAddress". The conflict occurred in database "DomainModel.SeasideHeightsEntities", table "dbo.Addresses", column 'ID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Still at a loss as to how to model this properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is... which gets deleted first, the customer, or the mailing address?  You can't delete them both at the same time, the deletes will happen in a sequence.  When the first gets deleted, it fails the rule b/c the second hasn't been deleted yet.

From what I can see of your model, I'd not use the foreign keys to handle this logic, I'd handle it during object validation by putting a [Required] attribute on the MailingAddress property instead of the foreignkey.

You should also consider additional implementation logic to ensure that the MailingAddress is part of the Addresses collection.

Comment: Well neither should be allowed to be deleted so long as the customer has a mailing address! That's part of the reason why I think a FK relationship makes sense. This worked fine in my normal database-first EF program. Any suggestions on how I could implement this with the code-first approach? Thanks!

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  Something has to own the relationship.  In this case, it looks to me like the Customer is the domain aggregate, and therefore should be in charge of controlling its mailing address.

Comment: I can see how that makes sense. In that case, do you know if it's possible to specify via the CTP fluent API that when a customer is deleted it should delete the associated mailing address (or other entities that it "owns") as well?

Comment: yes, it's part of the fluent API, when you call the fluent api on your reference it has a WillCascadeOnDelete() method, check this article for detailed code:  http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/19/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx